# Texture Not Rendering in C++ SDL OpenGL(glut)

Tags: opengl, c++, textures, sdl

I don't understand why my texture("texture.bmp"), is not showing on the screen. Please help me.

The whole drawing function:

```
///HERE EVERYTHING IS BEING RENDERED
void Main::display(){

    int startTime = GetTickCount();

    ///BACKGROUND COLOR
    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    ///LOAD THE IDENTITY MATRIX FOR THE DRAWING
    glLoadIdentity();

    ///SO EVERYTHING HAS THE CORRECT SIZE
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

    ///CAMERA MOVEMENT
    glTranslatef(cameraX, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    ///THE SUN
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

        glVertex2f(-3.0f, 2.0f); // The bottom left corner
        glVertex2f(-3.0f, 2.5f); // The top left corner
        glVertex2f(-2.5f, 2.5f); // The top right corner
        glVertex2f(-2.5f, 2.0f); // The bottom right corner
    glEnd();

    ///THE GROUND
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(0.5f,2.0f,0.5f);

        glVertex2f(-20.0f,-4.0f);
        glVertex2f(-20.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex2f(130.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex2f(130.0f,-4.0f);

        glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

        for(float i = 0.0f ; i < 100.0f ; i += 5.0f){
            glVertex2f(i,-1.0f);
            glVertex2f(i,ranFloat[static_cast<int>(i-4.0f)]);
            glVertex2f(i+1.0f,ranFloat[static_cast<int>(i-4.0f)]);
            glVertex2f(i+1.0f,-1.0f);
        }
    glEnd();

    ///THE GRASS
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(0.0f,0.5f,0.0f);

        glVertex2f(-20.0f,-1.2f);
        glVertex2f(-20.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex2f(130.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex2f(130.0f,-1.2f);
    glEnd();

    ///THE PLAYER
    glTranslatef(playerX,playerY,0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

        glVertex2f(-3.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex2f(-3.0f,0.0f);
        glVertex2f(-2.8f,0.0f);
        glVertex2f(-2.8f,-1.0f);
    glEnd();


    ///TEXTUREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    int X = 0;
    int Y = 0;
    int Width = 1;
    int Height = 1;

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(X, Y, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(X + Width, Y, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(X + Width, Y + Height, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(X, Y + Height, 0);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    ///CLOUDS
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        for(float i = 0.0f ; i < 100.0f ; i += 5.0f){
            glVertex2f(i,3.0f);
            glVertex2f(i,4.0f);
            glVertex2f(i+4.0f,3.0f);
            glVertex2f(i+4.0f,4.0f);
        }
    glEnd();

    if(Input::flying){
        Input::returnFly(0.007f);
    }

    elapsedMS = GetTickCount() - startTime; // Time since start of loop
    //std::cout << "FPS: " << elapsedMS << std::endl;

    ///THE ACTUAL MOVEMENT
    playerY += playerFly;//*elapsedMS;
    playerX += cameraSpeed*-1;//*elapsedMS;
    cameraX += cameraSpeed;//*elapsedMS;

    ///SWAP THE BUFFERS FOR SMOOTH RENDERING
    glutSwapBuffers();
  }
```

The rest of my code has nothing to do with the texture loading. The loading is not the problem, because I didn't get any errors.

Comment: why on earth are you using sdl and glut togther?

Comment: SDL for loading the image and glut for opengl, to draw the texture(SDL image).

Comment: SDL has both opengl context creation and texture loading functionality. You should not have required two frameworks that do the same things, (and mess up each other's work?)

Comment: I actually prefer glut, but I don't know if I can load images with glut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking that your SDL_Surface* is valid? Are you sure that your "Mode" is RGB/RGBA and not BGRA/BGR?

I think the problem is that you need to pass the Surface->format->BytesPerPixel as the third argument to glTexImage2D instead of Mode.

Also, I would set the Min/Mag filter before calling glTexImage2D.

Like this:

```
void Main::loadStuff() {
    GLuint texture = 0;

    SDL_Surface* Surface = SDL_LoadBMP("texture.bmp");
    if (!Surface) {
        // error, report?
        return;
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    int Mode = GL_RGB;

    if(Surface->format->BytesPerPixel == 4) {
        Mode = GL_RGBA;
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Surface->format->BytesPerPixel, Surface->w, Surface->h, 0, Mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Surface->pixels);


    SDL_FreeSurface(Surface);
}
```

Bonus points if you want to work in `std::unique_ptr` for you surface.

Comment: Can't edit, but, also noticed that `GLuint texture` is local to `void Main::loadStuff()` - that could certainly be part of the problem, too (when you try to rebind in "The drawing of the texture:" portion, where does that `texture` come from?

Comment: It is a static variable I defined in the Main header file

Comment: Ah! The local one is taking over, that's probably why. Get rid of the one at the top of `void Main::loadStuff()` then, it's taking over.

Comment: But how can I draw now. I need the texture variable but now it is only defined in de loadStuff function, and I need in in the display function.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, get rid of the one local to loadStuff and have loadStuff set your static variable in the Main header file.

Comment: An even better solution would be to make your loadStuff more generic: change from `void Main::loadStuff()` to `GLuint Main::loadStuff(const char* imgPath)` -- now you can pass the `imgPath` to `SDL_LoadBMP` and load any texture from a BMP file. (Note: This would require you to change your draw function a little bit, since you'd now have multiple textures)

Comment: The problem is, still nothing is getting shown on the window...

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the full code of your draw function? That "texture" needs to come from "loadStuff" and I'm guessing they're not the same (see above, try printing their values to the console). What does the main header file look like? (I'm guessing the texture in draw is 0/null/etc)

Comment: Okay, the image is showing but it is glitchy as hell here a picture: http://prntscr.com/8yoz08 The black quad is the image, you can barely see it and it is rendered 3 times upside down :/

Comment: Did you fix your call to `glTexImage2D` ? What is the rest of your drawing code? Is the image correct, just rendered multiple times upside down?

Comment: Check my question, I edited it and now you can see the whole render function.

Comment: IT WORKS! I tried to load a .png image and now it works. thank you so much for your help! :)